# Добавление видео на сайт скриншот

Tags: php, видео, mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой, у меня есть страница где я добавляю видео то есть HTML код с сервиса Youtube.com мне нужно что бы когда я отправил данные в бд, на той странице где я вывожу все видео, что бы был не видео плеер а скриншот, к примеру 
как тут: cyberarena.tv/video_list.php(не реклама) спасибо...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://img.youtube.com/vi/[VIDEO_ID]/[0-3].jpg

К примеру адрес видео http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcEzx5HLYEw
то скриншот будет по адресу http://img.youtube.com/vi/jcEzx5HLYEw/0.jpg